# A proper way to reduce provided data set in UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am provided a reference to a NSArray that contains data items. In my Custom View controller that acts as a data source for the table view, I interpret each item and present it as a cell.
So far so good.

Now there is a requirement from my colleagues to implement a filter, that will be based on values of one of the item's properties.
This property has enumerated values (4 of them). So when I apply the filter, i should see only items that match the particular value.
My question is  how should I approach this filtering of that data.

1) Should I set the _data private variable to point to the original data source, and then override the "data" property getter to take into account the filtering?

2) Should I generate a separate filteredData array inside my controller?
3) Some other approach?

NOTE> coredata+fetched resultscontr. is out of the question. The number of items never will be more then 150-200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the second choice. Having a filteredDatasource is more convenient. This way, you are able to know , not only the cells you should display, but also how many they are etc. Moreover, if in the future you want to sort them and use sections, you will be far more flexible.

For example when you implement the method `– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` which is called many times internally using the filtered data source you do not have to traverse through the array's objects many times so as to see which of them should pass the filter. You just return `[filteredDatasource count]`. This is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

In the apps I work on we have a array of all items and a copy which is the one the datasource refers to. When a filter is applied it replaces the copy but is based on the original array. So I guess #2.